# Set title for arrow in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've used the arrow to draw a vertical line and I would like to title it so it's shown in the key. Is there a way to do it? As far as I can tell for the manual, there's no `title` option in the syntaxis for `arrow`, but I'm sure there's a workaround.

The only thing I think of is drawing the arrow with the same color as something outside the plot range and use its title, but it's rather clumsy.

I'm using the terminal `pngcairo`, just in case it's relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnuplot will ignore anything with an invalid value (1/0 for instance).  You can take advantage of this to plot what you want.

Suppose that we set a vertical line with

```
set arrow from 1,graph 0 to 1,graph 1 nohead lt 0
```

Now, if I want this to be in the key, I can just plot a line with lt 0 but specify the y-value as 1/0.  This will insert it in the key, but will not actually draw the line.

```
plot [-3:3] x**2 t "X Squared", 1/0 t "Vertical Line" lt 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can plot something `with vectors`, which will give a `title` in the key. It plots arrows based on data points.  The `using` statement is *x*:*y*:Δ*x*:Δ*y* where the tail is positioned at (*x*, *y*) and the head is at (*x*+Δ*x*, *y*+Δ*y*).  For a vertical line, you can turn off the arrow head and use Δ*x* of zero:

```
set terminal pngcairo dashed
set output 'plot.png'

set angles degrees
set xrange [0:360]
set yrange [-2:2]

plot sin(x), '-' using 1:(-2):(0):(4) with vectors nohead lc rgb 'black' title '90 degrees'
90
e
```

[image: Result of gnuplot script]